# Is the PHP serialize a must if I want to store an object or aray to mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I just want to make sure is `serialize` something I have to do if I want to save PHP object to mySQL database.

I found some articles saying that use `serialize` to keep the original form of data.

I need some explanation since I just a beginner. Thank you :)

Comment: Usually you just store an object in one (or more) tables. Are you sure you wish to store an object in a column? Storing it as a string like that makes it much much harder to use as the point of storing things in a  relational database is to be able to search work with the data stored there.

Comment: Actually i want to store the array data which contains the set of values. So should I use `serialize` or not?

Comment: Serialize is fine if you just want input/output. If you want to be able to search it or access only parts of it, read about database normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question without a single good answer, very opinion-based. A couple things to keep in mind:

Is it useful to keep raw data, besides the data you're going to store in your database columns?

How are you going to use the data? Generally, you would store each data in its own database table column. If you only keep the original data "just in case I need it later", you might as well store it in a single column in serialized form.

How are you going to store it? I personally prefer NOT to use the PHP serialize format, but rather JSON instead. This is because:

1. JSON is a format that can be decoded by languages other than PHP out of the box, which makes it more portable to other systems.
2. Certain database types and versions have dedicated support for JSON in the form of JSON data column, which allows for faster processing.

Comment: The data I want to store is an array that contains a set of values ​​and the amount is very much. The data I will use to do some things in my program. Is the use of `serialize` very necessary in storing arrays to the database?

Comment: PHP arrays do not map directly to databases, so you will need to serialize. Which format you use, depends on personal preference. As mentioned above, I'd personally go for JSON.

Comment: HOWEVER. If the data you store is always in the same structure and with a fixed amount of values, you may want to consider storing the data in separate columns. For example, a user's first name, last name and email address should be placed in their own columns. This way you can better leverage the power of database indexes and SQL `where` clauses.